# What should be the correct javascript syntax in this case?

Tags: javascript, html, syntax

I have a code that is a mix of HTML and js. I cannot get it correct.

```
location.description + '<br><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="showStreet;">ShowStreet </a><br>'+ location.lat + '<br> + location.lng
```

Can anyone help me with it?

Comment: What is it meant to do? you are also missing a single quote from the end of that. Thus leaving the string open.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have two problems in that:

- You were missing `'` after `location.lat + '<br>`
- You were not suffixing the function `showStreet` with `()`

**Try this:**

```
location.description + '<br><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="showStreet();">ShowStreet </a><br>'+ location.lat + '<br>' + location.lng
```

**Note:** You might want to add the `return` keyword for your function depending on whether you want to cancel it at some point.

Comment: +1 Probably also worth mentioning the `return` thing if he wants to cancel.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder: Thanks in the first place, the OP knows the best whether he needs the return keyword or not, however i have mentioned that.

Comment: would not the `href="jaascript:void(0)"` result in the link not being followed any way?

Comment: @thecoshman: There is no link to be followed in that, as can be seen the OP has to run a function on clicking that link.

Answer (score 1):

Did you mean `onclick="showStreet()"` (instead of `onclick="showStreet;"`)?
From your question, it's unclear what the problem is.

Answer (score -1):

```
location.description + '<br><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="showStreet();">ShowStreet </a><br>'+ location.lat + '<br>' + location.lng
```

You have to call a function inside onclick and there you were missing parenthesis. And also a single quote after the last `<br>`

Comment: @Sarfraz: The thing he actually corrected, he corrected just fine (the call *was* missing the parens). If the OP *also* wants the onclick to be cancellable, then yes, he'd also need to add a `return`. @rahul: Does Google know you're using their intellectual property? (http://www.google.co.uk/permissions/guidelines.html) ;-)

Comment: @T.J. Crowder: You are right but I did not down vote. Rahul knows I do not down vote, for this reason i suggested him to correct his answer :)

Comment: @Sarfraz: I didn't say you downvoted. And your original unedited comment *didn't* tell him about the other problem, it just said "That won't work." full stop.